# psql to sqlcmd options

Tags: psql, sqlcmd

I am moving from PostgreSQL to MS SQL server, I would like to know if there is an an equivalent  to \h an \i options in psql to sqlcmd. Also, how can I get SQL statement description in Microsoft SQL server management.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> \i that is file sql execution, you could do something like below.

**For external Command**

`sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql`

**Inside sqlcmd Command**

`:r <filename>`

> \h that is sql help, you could do something like below.

`:Help` could be used.

Comment: Thanks for the response I have checked it, :r indeed works , but :Help is used to list the sqlcmd commands